# good json lib like ios JSONModel

Tags: java, android, json

can tell me if android  have the same lib link

https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel

or

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/JSONModel/

I  parse JSON only need write set and get, and then make JSON to object mapping and serialization.

Comment: gson does that, i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). Both are very easy to use, I prefer Gson because it works without annotations in the POJOs. There's lots of examples to be found on how to use them to serialize and deserialize JSON.

Comment: at Gson i only found one example,where is more examples on how to use them to serialize and deserialize JSON

Answer (score 3):

Gson does a great job for this;

You can read a little tutorial about it here which should get you started;
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: are you have another tutorial,this is my need, i want to parse the json  like this.

Comment: Hmm? Don't know exactly what you're asking

Comment: i want to more example like your link,can you give some other link?

Answer (score 0):

You also have [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/) lib that has nice features, perfs, provides alternatives to annotations and is easy to use.

Comment: if Genson==Gson ,the two is difference or is the same

Comment: no they are completely different, two different libs with some features in common but many differences. For example Gson uses only fields in ser/deser, Genson can use anything, fields,getters,setters, constructors, etc

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the lib [FastJson](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson) , it is fast than protocol buf and jackson , you can try this .

Answer (score 0):

maybe FastPojo help you, a wilde card pojo class

https://github.com/BaselHorany/FastPojo

usually you make a modle class like this

```
public class Msg {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Double doub;
    private Boolean bool;

    public Msg(String id,.....,.........) {
        this.id = id;
        ........
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    ........

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    ........

}
```

for each variable you define its type and make setter and getter voids and pass it in a Routine process and then you use it like this usually

```
//set
Msg msg = new Msg();
msg.setId(id);
msg.setName(name);
........
//get
msg.getId();
.........
```

BUT with FastPojo you dont need custom modle because it is a "Wilde Card class" that can define objects type and then set and get them appropriately you just set and get directly> so:
Usage

just copy the class to your project

```
FastPojo msg = new FastPojo();
msg.set1(id);
msg.set2(name);
msg.set3(1.55);
msg.set4(true);
//get first variable where s is the type you should remember it s for string, i for int, d for double and b for boolean.
msg.get1i();//get id int
msg.get2s();//get string name
msg.get3d();//get double 1.55
msg.get4b();//get boolean true
```